# PHP not loading oauth module in xampp and wamp in windows 32 bit system

Tags: rest, oauth

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803265/how-to-install-php-extension-locally-on-wamp
```

I followed this link and downloaded both the oauth files available in the link

Edited the dll in extension folder and edited the php.ini file

But the extension is not loading.

Iam working with magento so i need the oauth module to be enabled badly for my rest apis to work

Has anybody solved this issue?

Comment: can you say me for what purpose you want to use Rest API?

Comment: I need to put some customers and get some catalog products

Comment: @chanz: I am continuing it from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento/13858760 as i have to wait till monday to install linux in my system. so was trying with xampp and wamp as well