# SSH2 in php, wamp,windows

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, libssh2, ssh2-sftp

I have to connect sftp link and have to put data in sftp link.

I want to connect sftp link through function `ssh2_connect`.

My trouble is that whenever i am running that function i am getting error `Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()`.

Then I downloaded `libssh2.tar.gz` and `ssh2.tgz` but i dont know where to install / put these files.

I am using - Windows 7, Wamp server, mysql, php
P.O. - If i have to run come commands then please tell also where i have to run that commands.
Thanks in advance
IF there is another way to connect sftp link please share that also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803265/how-to-install-php-extension-locally-on-wamp

Comment: @DarkBee Hi, I added php_ssh2.dll file extension in path wamp\bin\php\..\ext also added line in php.ini file. (Downloaded file - http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) but still getting error Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Comment: U need to restart the apache service :-). Make sure u've edited the right php.ini. WAMP uses 2 ini's, one for CLI and one the webmode

Comment: still not working...same error i am getting `Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()`

Comment: What version of Apache are you running, and what version of WAMPServer please. Also are you 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: The files you have downloaded look to me like they are for a unix/linus system and not windows so be careful.

Comment: @RiggsFolly appache version = 2.4.4, php version = 5.4.16, windows 7 (32 bit), mysql version = 5.6.12, wamp version =2.4
can you give me exact link fom where i can download my dll file and save in path wamp\bin\php\..\ext

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the dll files in the "wamp\bin\php*.*.*\ext\" path and add line "extension=[name_of_your_file.dll]" to the php.ini file in the "wamp\bin\php*.*.*\" path