# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() And Openssl is also Enabled

Tags: php, openssl, wamp

My open ssl service available in php.info ,Still getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() 
Before this i changed dll files in php folder - `libssh2` AND in ext path php_ssh2.dll and php_ssh2.pdb

Please help
this also  i had tried -
[SSH2 in php, wamp,windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800993/ssh2-in-php-wamp-windows?noredirect=1#comment38500937_24800993)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050231/php-function-ssh2-connect-is-not-working